# How expensive is it to create an exception in PHP?

Tags: php, exception

Back story: I have a class that handles a database query. The problem is that the query is only executed when needed, so this may sometimes be a bit far away from the place it's created. Now if the wrapped SQL query fails, it becomes difficult to trace it back to it's origin.

Now the idea is this: I'll create a generic exception object (which gives me backtrace and everything) when creating that wrapper. When something happens during the actual execution, the pre-generated exception can be used to find the source of the problem when debugging.

This inevitably leads to the question: How expensive is it to generate an `Exception` object beforehand? Is it even a smart thing to do? How would you debug deferred SQL execution?

To clarify the process, here's some pseudo code:

```
$list = new QueryWrapper("SELECT ...");

$list->setPage(5);

// Later...
foreach ($list as $entry) { ... }
```

Only when the foreach actually accesses `$list` is the query executed.

**Update:** Here's a minimalistic implementation:

```
public function __construct($query, ... $params = array()) {
        ... 
        $this->createTrace     = new \Exception();
}

// called by the Iterator's rewind()  
private function runQuery() {
    try {
        // execute query;
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception(
            sprintf(
                'Exception thrown after SQL error (created as %s)',
                $this->createTrace->getTraceAsString()
            ),
            0, $e
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating an Exception which might be thrown later sounds like a rather unusual idea and is likely not what I would expect. I mean, the normal case would be to NOT throw an exception. So, most of the time you would create an Exception which is likely be never thrown/used.

An Exception which is thrown later in program flow will give you the stack trace anyway, so in my opinion: dont bother and dont do that.

Comment: It's not that I don't want the stack trace - it's just that I need to see where the failing statement was created.

Comment: @Dave Vogt then add a logger in the query wrapper and log creation instead of misusing exceptions

Comment: that sounds like a good idea. I'd still have to identify the query wrapper somehow, and create a backtrace, tho.

Answer (score 1):

In a production environment, I believe that the performance "loss" would be negligible as creating an `Exception` object is the same as creating any class, which is virtually no hit whatsoever.

---

I'm not sure that this is the correct way to approach your problem however.. Is this what you're expecting to do?

```
$list = new QueryWrapper("SELECT ...");
$list->exception = new Exception();
```

?

Comment: No, the exception would be created in the constructor.

Comment: Fair enough, well even so the first statement sticks - It wouldn't make a difference, but as mentioned by @Max an exception should give you a full stack trace anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A simple 3v4l test:

- create exception: https://3v4l.org/ACHS0/perf#output
- do not create exception: https://3v4l.org/XRojg/perf#output

The difference seems to be minimal (on the 3v4l.org hardware, about 1-10 us per exception creation - that's less than a millisecond if you run a few dozen queries per request, not really relevant even for a high-performance web application).